# PowerShell Script / Tool that Provides the User Permissions for a document library and sub folders

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have recently migrated File Server from On-premise file server to SharePoint online using Native SharePoint online migration tool. However, the tool doesnt provide the list of permissions mapped against Root folder / sub folder / files. I would like to retrieve this information using Powershell script. Any help, welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Ranjith

Answer (score 1):

Here is a permission report script for SharePoint online: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the Sharing Reports for SharePoint Online to achieve this.

Go to site contents-> Site usuage,clik "run report". You would get a list of permission of all contents in the site. Then yo ucould filter the list to the library.

About the Sharing Reports for SharePoint Online, please refer to this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/10c5b4c2-d8f9-42b5-8993-30b5ac5f030e/sharepoint-online-new-features-sharing-reports-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharegate tool/ SPMT tool to get report from source and destination. Once the Source and destination reports are exported into excel, you can compare those reports and find the permissions.

**Note:** ShareGate provides 15 days trial/ SPMT free of cost